# Comparar dos atributos en XSLT

Tags: html, xsl, xslt

!Buenas!

Necesito comparar dos atributos en XSLT para que me muestre unos datos. Si existe otra forma de hacerlo, estoy abierto a ideas.

Tengo un **XML** donde aparecen varios Alumnos de esta forma:

```
        <alumno>
        <nombre>Guadalupe</nombre>
        <apellido>Lotas</apellido>
        <DNI>54368436</DNI>
        <fechanacimiento>
            <dia>17</dia>
            <mes>10</mes>
            <anio>1999</anio>
        </fechanacimiento>
        <matriculado asignatura="LM" nota="SB"/>
        <matriculado asignatura="AD" nota="SS"/>
    </alumno>
```

Y también una asignaturas de esta forma

```
<asignaturas>
    <asignatura codigo="POO">
        <titulo>Programación orientada a objetos</titulo>
        <curso>Primero</curso>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura codigo="AD">
        <titulo>Acceso a datos</titulo>
        <curso>Segundo</curso>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura codigo="ED">
        <titulo>Entornos de desarrollo</titulo>
        <curso>Primero</curso>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura codigo="LM">
        <titulo>Lenguajes de Marcas</titulo>
        <curso>Primero</curso>
    </asignatura>
</asignaturas>
```

Como se puede ver, el alumno esta matriculado en una de ellas y esta en forma de atributo, y el código de cada asignatura también. Necesito que en una tabla me aparezca **el curso de la asignatura que el alumno esta matriculado**.

Y esto es lo que llevo realizado:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="universidad">
  
  <html>
  
  <head></head>
  
  <body>
    
    <h2>ALUMNOS</h2>
    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="alumnos/alumno" mode="tabla"/>
  
  </body>
  
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  
  <xsl:template match="matriculado">
  
  <xsl:value-of select="@asignatura"/>,
  
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  <xsl:template match="alumno" mode="tabla">
  
  <b><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/></b>
  
  <table border="2">
  
<tr>
    <th>Titulo</th>
    <th>Curso</th>
    <th>Nota</th>
</tr>

 <tr>
  <td><xsl:apply-templates select="matriculado"/></td>
  <td>prueba</td>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="matriculado/@nota"/></td>
  </tr>
    
  </table>
  
  <br></br>
  
  </xsl:template>
  
  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Y en donde tengo **prueba**, necesito que se muestre el curso de la asignatura en cuestión. ¿Como hago para que se muestre?.

Agradecería mucho una ayuda, llevo atascado en esto mas tiempo de lo previsto... Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiando la palabra prueba por:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//asignatura[string(@codigo)=string('matriculado/@asignatura')]/titulo"/>
```

Comment: He tenido que ajustar el `match`, pero si ha funcionado. !Muchas gracias!